# Create twitter share/tweet link in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I´m trying to create a custom "twitter-share" button in Wordpress. I am new to PHP, I just want the article link to appear in the text field.

I know the following syntax is wrong, but I imagine it would look something like this:

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?url=<php get_url(); ?>" target="blank" title="Share this on Twitter">
```

Please help.

Comment: can you please tell  what expected output?

Comment: I want the twitter window to pop-up and the link of the actual article to appear in it...

Comment: do you have referance link??

Comment: https://www.infinitesense.org/news/how-to-spot-fake-news - that would be the link i want to implement in the tweet, for example

Comment: please check below code

Answer (score 1):

Share on twitter code this will open window exactly that given in reference site.

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
      data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
      data-via="wpbeginner"
      data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>"
      data-related="syedbalkhi:Founder of WPBeginner"
      data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
```

Link for reference   :

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-twitters-official-tweet-button-in-wordpress/

Comment: Okay,please make it completed if any wants to use they can find easily